# Converting dates when importing from CSV, OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, date-formatting

I'm importing data from a csv, and I'm trying to set a specific date to today's date.

Data in the csv if formatted this way:

[image: filedate column in a csv]

All data in that column are dates and are formatted exactly the same. I read in the data with `df = pd.read_csv(r'<filapath.csv>)` at the moment.

Then this is run to convert all instances of '7/21/2020' into today's date:

`df['filedate'] = np.where(pd.to_datetime(df['filedate']) == '7/21/2020', pd.Timestamp('now').floor(freq='d'),df['filedate'])`

I receive this error: `pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-14 00:00:00`

I don't want to use `errors='coerce'` because the column will always be 100% populated with real dates, and I will later need to filter the dataframe by date. There seems to be some "ghost" precision in the csv data I can't see. I cannot modify the csv column in this case and I can't use any packages outside of pandas and numpy.

Comment: did you find out which line from the csv causes the error? besides my suggestion to try `.loc`, I can't seem to reproduce the error with some date strings from the example you posted.

Comment: Each line can cause the error. Which is the baffling part! For example, if I copy the column and populate my own dates, formatted exactly as the auto-populated dates in the column, my code works fine. I think there's some ghost formatting (not sure what else to call it) hidden in the cells.

Comment: did you check what happens if you cast the column to datetime upfront, `df['filedate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['filedate'])`?

Answer (score 1):

...or alternatively `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['filedate'] == '7/21/2020', 'filedate'] = pd.Timestamp('now').floor(freq='d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .replace() function.

```
df['filedate'].replace({'7/21/2020':pd.Timestamp('now').floor(freq='d')})
```

Comment: it should be noted that this has to be applied before converting the column to datetime, i.e. while it is still of dtype object / string.